# how to get all public rooms on openfire server from android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire

I am working on multichatuser in android reading on various article in different websites and also in stackoverflow. I am trying to query the server to return all public rooms available without knowing this names of the rooms in advance. So that client can display a list of all public rooms available and join them accordingly.

So far I have done following things:

```
//room11 is the list array
//lv is the list view
  Collection<HostedRoom> rooms = MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, service);  
                for(HostedRoom room : rooms) { 
                     room11.add(room.getName());
                     }     
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listitems,R.id.list_content, room11);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It does not show any error nor add anything in the listview.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use this link i hope it helps u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296022/cannot-get-list-of-public-rooms-from-xmpp-server-on-android